# Wordpress website not displaying images on certain safari browsers

Tags: ios, wordpress, safari

I have a weird situation, I am developing a site I can see all of the images well on my mac as well as an android phone but on my iPhone and my friends mac, and iPad it is not displaying the images when using safari. Is there something I need to add to the files for this to display properly all through out?

Thanks all feedback welcomes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears these assets are linked using `https` but there is not a valid SSL on the site.  So on the devices where it works you have either authorized the SSL or bypassed it, but the other devices have not.

If you open up the [Developer Tools in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) and view the console you can see the assets with issues along with the error message... "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE"

Comment: I removed the certificate it had expired would this have been the root of my issue? it is still not displaying images.

Comment: You will need to either install a valid certificate or update your URLs for those assets to use `http` instead of `https`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has the same problem. For me the problem was that a plugin "Ewww image optimizer" converted images to webP, these were then cached and served by cloudflare and wouldn't load in safari