# Issues with the display of a WordPress website on certain versions of Safari browsers, but not consistently across all versions

Tags: wordpress

I am aware of a situation where a WordPress website appears to function properly when accessed from Android browsers, but encounters issues displaying images on some versions of Safari browsers on Apple devices. What could be the underlying cause of this issue?[This is image of the site from safari browser where it does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWvV1.jpg)
[This is image of the site from another safari browser where it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx84p.jpg)

After consulting with ChatGPT, I attempted to resolve the issue by following their recommendation to deactivate plugins until the problem was resolved. However, this approach proved unsuccessful. In addition, I also cleared the cache on Cloudflare, but the issue with image display on certain versions of Safari browsers persisted.
I have tried the answers here -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174275/wordpress-website-not-displaying-images-on-certain-safari-browsers
None of them work,I had smush and "ewww image optimizer" and I deactivated them and I still have this error, also my website hosting says that everything fine with the ssl.

Comment: I assume that something change my images to webp and it doesnt work perfectly in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Both ewww and smush can generate webp images. If the issue is that webp images are being loaded and remain unseen by relatively old browsers, I would recommend downloading a 'regenerate thumbnails' plugin and executing that to recreate your thumbnails. Once done, clear any caches that you may have. If the issue persists, check your htaccess for any unremoved rewrite rules from smush or ewww that force webp loading, also check the wp-config.php file for further webp rewrite rules and remove them.